Django stripe and stripe webhook error : {"error": "Missing stripe signature"}
please, I need your help. I'm trying to set up a striped payment system in the django app. However, I can't seem to connect the webhook to my logic. In addition, the handle_checkout_session function which should send a message after the success of each payment does not send any message. However, when I make a payment it works fine. But, Webhook and handle_checkout_session doesn't work. Your help will be welcome... Here is my code.
def stripe_config(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        stripe_config = {'publicKey': settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}
        return JsonResponse(stripe_config, safe=False)

login_required(login_url="login")
def stripe_payment(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        domain_url = getattr(settings, 'DOMAIN_URL')
        success_url = domain_url + reverse('stripe_success') + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'
        cancel_url = domain_url + reverse('stripe_cancel')
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        order_id = request.GET.get('order_id')

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, is_ordered=False, order_number=order_id)
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                client_reference_id=request.user.id if request.user.is_authenticated else None,
                success_url=success_url,
                cancel_url=cancel_url,
                payment_method_types=['card'],
                mode='payment',
                line_items=[
                    {
                        'price_data': {
                            'currency': 'eur',
                            'unit_amount': int(order.order_total * 100),
                            'product_data': {
                                'name': "Buy now",
                            },
                        },
                        'quantity': 1,
                    }
                ]
            )

            return JsonResponse({
                'sessionId': checkout_session['id']
            })
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({
                'error': 'Order does not exist or has already been processed.'
            }, status=404)
        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            return JsonResponse({
                'error': str(e)
            }, status=500)

    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method.'}, status=400)

@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    endpoint_secret = settings.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET

    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META.get('HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE')
    print(sig_header)

    if sig_header is None:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Missing stripe signature'}, status=400)

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=400)

    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        handle_checkout_session(session)

    return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, status=200)

def handle_checkout_session(session):
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(payment__payment_id=session['id'])
        order.is_ordered = True
        order.save()

        ordered_products = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order_id=order.id)
        subtotal = 0
        tax = 0
        taxdhl = 0
        grand_total = 0
        grand_total_dhl = 0

        for i in ordered_products:
            subtotal += i.product_price * i.quantity
            tax += (2*subtotal)/100
            taxdhl = 1
            grand_total += subtotal + tax
            grand_total_dhl += grand_total + taxdhl

        user = order.user
        current_site = get_current_site(None)
        mail_subject = 'Thank you for your order!'
        message = render_to_string('orders/order_received_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'order': order,
            'grand_total': grand_total,
            'grand_total_dhl': grand_total_dhl,
            'ordered_products': ordered_products,
            'tax': tax, 
            'taxdhl': taxdhl,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
        })

        from_email = 'Parisianist <customercare@parisianist.fr>'
        to_email = user.email

        mail = Mail(
            from_email=Email(from_email),
            to_emails=to_email,
            subject=mail_subject,
            html_content=message
        )

        try:
            sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
            response = sg.send(mail)
            print(f"SendGrid Response Status Code: {response.status_code}")
            print(f"SendGrid Response Body: {response.body.decode('utf-8') if response.body else 'No Body'}")
            print(f"SendGrid Response Headers: {response.headers}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while sending email: {e}")

    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        pass

I would really like to know what the problem is and how to correct it.

You should add logs on your code to see why the signature is missing. For debugging purposed only, you could pass in the signature manually in your code and ensure that you're following the webhook endpoint builder, https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks/quickstart?lang=python as a reference.
